# "Try and" versus "Try to"?

Tags: phrase-choice

> Try and hit me!
>
> Try to hit me!

Do the above example mean exactly the same and it's just a matter of preference to use which word?

> He tried to make it better.
>
> He tried and made it better.

The second example sounds strange when it comes to more formal sentence of that sort. Is it still a correct use of the phase?

Comment: The first one confirms the 'try' whereas the second one confirms the 'betterment'. ;)

Comment: what about _I will try and make it better_ versus _I will try to make it better_ ? thanks

Comment: I can mean almost exactly the same thing, sometimes. Compare your examples with this: *Look to your left and right.* vs. *Look to your left, then look to your right.*

Comment: @user49119. Okay again. The first one shows confidence and the latter one Confidence with probability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiom "Try and X" is a bold command or challenge.  This is colloquial, very informal, and does not sound professional.  It can sound child-like or naive.

**"Try and hit me!"** is an idiomatic expression that means **"Try to hit me!"** or perhaps more accurately, **"I dare you to try to hit me.  You cannot!"**  It can be said playfully or antagonistically.

**He tried to make it better.** This means that he attempted (tried; put forth effort) to make it better.  It doesn't indicate whether or not his attempt succeeded.

**He tried and made it better.** This is a standard conjunction.  It means that he attempted (tried; put forth effort), and did in fact make it better.  Note that this is not the "try and" idiom; it is not a command.

**I will try and make it better.** This is an awkward form.  It's not the typical idiomatic "challenge" command form.  It would surely be understood as **I will to make it better.** but it sounds a bit "off".

**I will try to make it better.**  This sounds natural, sincere, and professional.

An overbearing boss might say, "I need you to rework this.  But this time, **try and get it right**, ok?"  Note the idiomatic use of the command/challenge form.  It's a condescending tone.

Comment: Can you shed some light on _I will try and make it better_ versus _I will try to make it better_ too ? thanks

Comment: Updated as requested, along with some additional info.

Comment: The high-hat term for this is [hendiadys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendiadys)

Answer (score -2):

"try" means attempt ; to attempt to do or get something :

*Tim may not be good at math,but at least he tries.*

" try to do something" :

She tried to forget about what had happened .