# What is the difference (if any) between 'try and do something' and 'try to do something'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the difference (if any) between 'try and do something' and 'try to do something'? Do they mean the same thing? Are there any different connotations?

Comment: You are more likely to see _try to_ in formal or written material, and to hear _try and_ in informal conversation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Try and" versus "Try to"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16426/try-and-versus-try-to)